# Figurative usage of "salvific"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, figurative

Note that English is not my mother-tongue.

Would a native speaker understand that the following sentence is trying to convey that the protagonist is relieved by the fact that he'd been able to set down his heavy backpack, or would they rather be confused due to the theological origin of the term "salvific"?

> The backpack thumped down on the parched ground with a salvific thud.

If the word is bewildering (or plain wrong) here, what would be a better alternative?

**Update:**
After all the commotion I have reconsidered my word of choice and came up with an alternative, that, as I believe, is more apt in the context.

> The backpack thumped down on the parched ground with an extricating thud.

Comment: Perhaps you could use *saving* instead?

Comment: @tchrist somehow this doesn't do for me. It's too insipid. I'm looking for a strong word (and not even necessarily for an alternative for *salvific**, as pointed out in the question). Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: "a glorious thud" would transmit the idea that the weary traveller was taken to that spiritual place upon the sound of his heavy pack hitting the dusty earth.

Comment: @grateful despite the fact that I can't help but think you're being slightly sarcastic, I have to admit, I like that. Nonetheless, Max Williams has asserted that my word of choice is apt. Salvific it shall be!

Comment: Let me unreassure you. 90+% of native speakers will never have heard the word 'salvific', and I'm not sure if it has _ever_ been used as a transferred epithet.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. Thank you. Yet that wasn't the question. Would you say that my proposed usage is correct? If so, I'll happily use it and maybe teach some native speakers a new word.

Comment: I'll answer your actual questions, in simple terms. 'Would a native speaker understand that the following sentence is trying to convey that the protagonist is relieved by the fact that he'd been able to set down his heavy backpack?' ... Very, very few. I didn't. '[W]ould they rather be confused due to the theological origin of the term "salvific"?' No; they'd be confused because they didn't know the word. // 'Merciful' is often used as a transferred epithet (= signalling relief rather than giving mercy).

Comment: Very well. I conclude that it would be okay to use. As for the fact that many people might not know the word, that's okay for me. I have learned all of my English from reading words I didn't know before. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I wouldn't agree with 'OK to use'. I'd mark down a pupil using your sentence. The fact that it's not ungrammatical, and arguably semantically justifiable in some abstruse register, doesn't automatically shoot it to the top of the acceptability scale. And you did ask about whether it was 'bewildering', not just 'wrong'. If you wish to bewilder people , it works fine. // You misunderstand Max's response. '[I]t makes it sound like the really important thing here isn't the fact that the protagonist was able to finally stop carrying his heavy bag' is surely meant to _discourage_ the usage.

Comment: Now you got me truly interested, but the site keeps on nagging about extended discussions. I'd love to chat about the topic. Why would you mark a pupil down for it even though you say it's grammatically correct? Acceptability? Who raises the bar for that? You're right, though, about the bewilderment. I got so worked up in the question of actual correctness that I forgot about that aspect. Personally, I'm willing to deem my fellow humans (and potential readers) to be able to figure it out. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Sprottenwels, my comment was not intended to be sarcastic - I didn't previously know the word "salvific", and when I learnt its meaning, I wasn't very convinced of its use in this sentence. On second thoughts, that if you were writing a novel set in the US bible belt, or your character is a preacher, then I'd appreciate it more once I had looked it up.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a common word, but that doesn't mean it's a bad choice.  Writers often use uncommon words.

However, according to the dictionary, *salvific* means "Having the intention or power to bring about salvation or redemption", and it seems that the usage here implies that the **noise of it hitting the ground** ("thud") is the thing that saves or redeems the protagonist, rather than them not having to carry it any more.

That is to say, it makes it sound like the really important thing here isn't the fact that the protagonist was able to finally stop carrying his heavy bag, but rather that he loved the sound it made when it hit the ground.  If that's what you want to say, then I'd say it's fine as is.  I suppose the sound of it hitting the ground could represent the act of releasing it.